# Correcting Worldview-3 data to ground reflection/bottom of atmosphere with open source?

Tags: python, remote-sensing, software-recommendations, reflectance, worldview-3

I have some worldview-3 imagery that needs to be corrected from digital numbers to actual reflection values (preferably bottom-of-atmosphere). But the tricky part is I am looking for open source options.

I see that this is possible for worldview-2 with the Orfeo toolbox but worldview 3 isn't supported.

Is there a way to work around this by chance or does anyone have any other suggestions on python libraries/QGIS tools, etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting WV3 data to ToA reflectance is fairly straight forward and is well documented in the official [documentation](https://dg-cms-uploads-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/document/file/209/ABSRADCAL_FLEET_2016v0_Rel20170606.pdf).

Basically, the approach is to go from DN to ToA radiance (L), using this formula:

```
L = GAIN * DN * (abscalfactor / effectivebandwidth) + offset
```

These parameters can be found in the metadata of your satellite image.

From ToA radiance to ToA reflectance, the calculation is:

```
R = (L * d_es^2 * pi) / (E_sun * cos(theta))
```

With:
d_es being the earth-sun distance at the time of acquisition (in AUs).
E_sun is the band-averaged solar irradiance at 1 AU.
theta being the solar zenith angle.

More details can be read in the documentation.
All of the above is already available as a unofficial python package made available by my colleagues at https://github.com/DHI-GRAS/dg-calibration (note that this is code that is used internally only, and no support is available).

With the above, the main challenge is going from ToA to BoA information. For that, you can use Py6s - https://py6s.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.  It is not the easiest bit of code to set up, but it is Python.

Answer (score 0):

If BOA remains a challenge, you could although use high-level libraries such as [EOReader](https://github.com/sertit/eoreader) to load TOA reflectance bands:

```py
from eoreader.reader import Reader
from eoreader.bands import GREEN

prod = Reader().open(r"013848036010_01_P001_PSH")

# Load GREEN band into TOA reflectance
green = prod.load([GREEN])[GREEN]
green.plot(cmap="Greens")
```

[image]

> Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of EOReader.